# Create short link automatically with ShURLy

Tags: 7, nodes, workbench

I am using the [ShURLy](https://www.drupal.org/project/shurly) module to create short links for nodes. I would like to be able to create the short links when nodes are published, automatically, without having to do the extra steps of clicking on the Bookmarklet which opens a new page where I create the short link by clicking on a button/link.

How can I achieve this?

**update**

I am using workbench so I added

```
function my_node_workbench_moderation_transition($node, 
$previous_state, $new_state) {
// Generate the short link when it is published.
  if ($new_state == 'published' && $previous_state != $new_state) {
    $link = my_node_create_short_link($node->nid); 
  }
}
```

and the function `my_node_create_short_link` with [shorten](https://www.drupal.org/project/shorten) (shorten_url)

```
function my_node_create_short_link($node_id) {
 // Do not create the short link if already exists.
  $link = my_node_short_link_get($node_id);
  if ($link) {
      return $link;
  }
  else {
    $link = shorten_url(url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)));
    // Insert the link
    my_node_short_link_insert($node->nid;, $link);
    cache_set($node->nid;, $link);
    return $link;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As per the current module functionalities it does not seem to have that feature. So I think you need to create custom module.

In your custom module you will require to use [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x) (For Drupal 7) this hook to execute after each node is added. Then [Shurly](https://www.drupal.org/project/shurly) provides API to create short link, using those APIs you can create short link as an when required.

Hope this helps.. :)